# ResultSet.next() does not retrieve rows

Tags: java, derby, resultset

My code is about to access my database "toursdb" and get some result. I am using the command line and javadb. When I use `con.getMetaData` I do have results. Same when I use `rs.getMetaData`. I don't have connection problems. but my program bellow does print nothing.

```
//
import java.sql.*;
class JDBCTest
{
    public static void main(String ... args) {
        String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/c:/derbytuto/toursdb";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String query = "select * from AIRLINES";

        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

            while(rs.next()) {
                sb.append(rs.getString("AIRLINE") + " ");
                sb.append(rs.getString("AIRLINE_FULL" + "\n");
            }
            System.out.println(sb);
        } catch(SQLException x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
//
```

Comment: wont help @YCF_L. Do you have results when you run select query? Do you get stacktrace on console? When you say you get result in meta data, do you have column named airline and airline_full?

Comment: @YCF_L.  I am used to using `System.out.println(sb)` and get results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`con.getMetaData`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getMetaData()) *retrieves the number, types and properties of this ResultSet object's columns.* So, this doesn't guarantee, if your table has data or not.

If you program doesn't print anything that means, it isn't going inside `while` loop and that means there is no rows return for your query.

You might have populated the data, but ***you need to commit those data***, to get it reflected/save into your database ***else you won't see data in another database session.***

Comment: I did populate the database with data using provided scripts with javadb.

Comment: @1m9K You might have populated the data, but did you committed??

Comment: I am wrong. I just fired `java -jar %derby_home%\lib\derbyrun.jar ij` then fired `select * from airlines` and got nothing. my table is empty.

Comment: @1m9K As I said.

Comment: I did populate the table in a shell window, closed it. reopened it. and the table is empty. do i have to populate the table any time i open a new shell window?

Comment: @1m9K You didn't read my post completely. Please read the last line, which state the reason.

Comment: I re-run the script `ij> run 'loadTables.sql'` and I see there was no `COMMIT;`. I wrote it my self. re-run my program and hooray. Thank you.